# @font-face variant being used as default

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to create a bold variant of my regular font, but it seems to always just use the last defined font-face in the matching font family. Any ideas?

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: ProofMedium;
  src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ProofMedium;
  src: url("/fonts/ProofBold/ProofBold-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: "bold"; }

@font-face {
    font-family: ProofMedium2;
    src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

body{
  font-family:ProofMedium, san-serif;
}
.test{
  font-family:ProofMedium2, san-serif;
}
</style>
<body>
testing <b>testing</b> <span class="test">testing</span>
</body>
```

Edit: I'm using chrome

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing,

```
font-weight: "bold";
```

to

```
font-weight: bold;
```

I'm surprised the quotation marks matter, but apparently they do.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove inline style from div font-weight:normal;.

```html
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: "ProofMedium";
  src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: "normal"; }
@font-face {
  font-family: "ProofMedium";
  src: url("/fonts/ProofBold/ProofBold-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: "bold"; }

body{
  font-family:"ProofMedium", san-serif;
}
</style>
<div>testing</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: ProofMedium;
  src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ProofMedium;
  src: url("/fonts/ProofBold/ProofBold-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: "bold";
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ProofMedium2;
  src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

body {
  font-family: ProofMedium, san-serif;
}

.test {
  font-family: ProofMedium2, san-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
testing <b>testing</b> <span class="test">testing</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @font-face {
      font-family: "ProofMedium";
      src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf")format("truetype");
      font-weight: "normal"; 
    }
 @font-face {
      font-family: "ProofMedium-1";
      src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf")format("truetype");
      font-weight: "normal"; 
}
 @font-face {
  font-family: "ProofMedium-2";
  src: url("/fonts/ProofBold/ProofBold-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: "bold"; 
}

         body    {font-family: "ProofMedium", san-serif;}
  p.ProofMedium-1{font-family: "ProofMedium-1";}
  p.ProofMedium-2{font-family: "ProofMedium-2";}


<p class="ProofMedium-1">i am ProofMedium-1</p>
<p class="ProofMedium-1">i am ProofMedium-2</p>
```

use above like diffrent  font family names

Answer (score 0):

In CSS have the highest precedence over internal and external CSS. What you define as inline CSS will not be overwritten by any external or internal CSS. Since you mentioned `font-weight: normal`, that is only being executed. So it should work if you remove it.

Bonus: Do not mix things up. If you are using external/internal CSS follow that standard only. Mixing them with inline CSS will only create confusion.
In CSS, if there are multiple definitions of @font-face the last definition will be executed and will overwrite the previous definitions.

[Go through specificity in css](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

```html
<style> @font-face {
  font-family: "ProofMedium";
  src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: "normal";
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "ProofMedium";
  src: url("/fonts/ProofBold/ProofBold-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: "bold";
}

body {
  font-family: "ProofMedium", san-serif;
}

</style> 
<div>testing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: "ProofMedium";
    src: url("/fonts/ProofMedium/ProofMedium-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: "ProofMedium";
    src: url("/fonts/ProofBold/ProofBold-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  body {
    font-family: "ProofMedium", san-serif;
  }
  .font_medium {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .font_bold {
    font-weight: 700;
  }
</style>
<p class="font_medium">text</p>
<p class="font_bold">text</p>
```